# Marketing Spend Optimization Techniques

Tags: predictive-modeling, optimization, data-analysis, marketing

I need some help with market spend optimization. I’m working with a client who’s running an offline operation that’s primarily driven by online marketing (fb, google, twitter etc). They had asked me to analyze their marketing performance and recommend a strategy. So far, I have been able to do basic ROI calculations further broken down by geographic regions, time etc.

I was wondering what else I can do? Are there any existing marketing spend optimization models or marketing mix models that can be used here? I have decent analysis skills but don’t know much about marketing analytics. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try [portfolio optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portfolio_optimization), where you maximize something like the expected return while minimizing costs like risk.

To do that, you'll need to assign an expected return (for example, the ROI) and a risk (for example, ROI std) to each marketing platform.